# Apache Camel: exchange.getException() vs CamelExceptionCaught property

Tags: apache-camel

Sometimes when I debug route I see exception in exchange, other times exception goes to CamelExceptionCaught property. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the error handler handles the exception it moves the exception from exchange.getException to the exchange property. This is done so the error handler and Camel knows it has been handled. If the exchange is then continued routed and a new exception is thrown/set on the exchange, then the error handler is able to react again.

See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html

Comment: FYI quote from your link: **then make notice that because you use handled(true), then the caused exception is no longer available from exchange.getException()**  I tried to use handled(false), but result the same